# HITs created using externalQuestion of MTurk were not working in the sandbox

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, mechanicalturk

I am new to MTurk and have been trying to implement my web app for point picking on this platform. I have successfully created a HIT using ExternalQuestion based on the tutorial from kaflurbaleen.blogspot.However, I realized the HIT was not working as desired when I tested the code in the sandbox. I found two issues as below.

1. I could not find the 'assignmentId' which was supposed to be appended to the URL. I checked the workersandbox and found the following URL before acceptance of the task
   https://workersandbox.mturk.com/mturk/preview?groupId=3JCELWMC4P1FAXE0GMTAW1L96T93VS

   As far as I understand, the 'assignmentId' should be appended to the URL after acceptance of the link above. And this parameter has to be returned to the Mturk server using the 'externalSubmit' method. I found only the following parameters after acceptance 
   hitId&prevHitSubmitted&prevRequester&requesterId&prevReward&hitAutoAppDelayInSeconds&groupId&signature
2. I also realized the app was not working as desired in the iframe. Each (mouse click + shift) should have created a red sphere as shown by the original website https://s3.amazonaws.com/www.pickvertex3js.com/vertexpicking.html.

I have tried to google for answers with little success. I am now at my wit's end with these two problems which are holding up my research. Any help will be very much appreciated. The codes for creating the HIT using BOTO3 are as follows.

```
import boto.mturk.connection

# define the host environment
sandbox_host = 'mechanicalturk.sandbox.amazonaws.com'
real_host = 'mechanicalturk.amazonaws.com'

mturk = boto.mturk.connection.MTurkConnection(
        host = sandbox_host,
        debug = 1
        )

# test the setup of boto by printing the version and account balance
print(boto.Version)
print(mturk.get_account_balance())

# link to my web app, which will be loaded by the iframe of Mturk
URL = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/www.pickvertex3js.com/vertexpicking.html" 

# setting task description of the iframe
title = "A Special HIT for Picking!" 
description = "Vertex picking!" 
keywords = ["3D mesh", "vertices"] 
frame_height = 500 # the height of the iframe holding the external hit 
amount = .00

# creating the HIT (task)
questionform = boto.mturk.question.ExternalQuestion( URL, frame_height ) 
response = mturk.create_hit( 
        title = title, 
        description = description, 
        keywords = keywords, 
        question = questionform, 
        reward = boto.mturk.price.Price( amount = amount),
        response_groups = ('Minimal', 'HITDetail'),
        ) 

# trying to get some outputs
HIT = response[0] 
assert response.status 

print ('[create_hit( %s, $%s ): %s]' % ( URL, amount, HIT.HITId ) )

# The response included several fields that will be helpful later
print ('Your HIT has been created. You can see it at this link:')
print ('https://workersandbox.mturk.com/mturk/preview?groupId={}'.format(HIT.HITTypeId))
print ('Your HIT ID is: {}'.format(HIT.HITId))
```

Answer (score 0):

I posted a reply on the AWS Developer Forums, too, but adding it here as well.

Here's the post: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=259228&tstart=0

Here's a copy of it for others on SO to benefit from:

I had a look at your HITs, and thought I'd offer some suggestions here. First, a few baseline things in case they help:

1) The assignmentId is being correctly added to your HITs. You can confirm this by loading up the page you shared (https://workersandbox.mturk.com/mturk/preview?groupId=3JCELWMC4P1FAXE0GMTAW1L96T93VS), clicking View Source, and scrolling to the  tag. You should see something that looks like this:

```
<iframe height="500" scrolling="auto" frameborder="0" align="center" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/www.pickvertex3js.com/vertexpicking.html?assignmentId=ASSIGNMENT_ID_NOT_AVAILABLE&amp;hitId=33K3E8REWX0SAJQPACFE1K5LTDBX8G" name="ExternalQuestionIFrame"></iframe>
```

2) Once you accept the HIT, you should see that tag change to look something like this:

```
<iframe height="500" scrolling="auto" frameborder="0" align="center" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/www.pickvertex3js.com/vertexpicking.html?assignmentId=38YMOXR4MW4S3P05XVRV37Q4QFGW6D&amp;hitId=33K3E8REWX0SAJQPACFE1K5LTDBX8G&amp;workerId=A39ECJ12CY7TE9&amp;turkSubmitTo=https%3A%2F%2Fworkersandbox.mturk.com" name="ExternalQuestionIFrame"></iframe>
```

3) I had a look at your code, and I can confirm that it works properly when loaded directly, but doesn't seem to work when placed in an IFRAME. I went a step further to try and figure out if the onDocumentMouseDown() method was even being invoked when shown in an IFRAME (I added an alert() in that function) and it is. My best guess, without diving deeper into it, is that there's something about The THREE library that isn't friendly with the IFRAME viewport. It's also possible that a line like this:

```
var mouse3D = new THREE.Vector3( ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1, 
-( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1, 
0.5 );
```

isn't using the right window (i.e., instead of using the IFRAME viewport, it's using the entire browser window, leading to weird/bad/wrong behavior).

The short version is that I don't think your issues are related to MTurk per-se, but rather related to IFRAME. As a not-ideal workaround, you could also consider linking the Worker directly to your page (instead of an IFRAME) and linking it back to the submit URL on MTurk. It's not ideal, but I think it could work.

Hope that helps.